# How can I apply scoped localization in net core without using resx files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I'm building a system which at the heart of it is a Content Management System. The system is used for a number of sites and each site is a different arrangement of modules - each of those modules has been built as a Razor Class Library (RCL). Each page created in the CMS can be given a culture, so the site can be multi-lingual. Each page also has a collection of translations (a dictionary) which are stored in the database for ease of management by the client. This works great for static labels on the razor pages and view components... BUT I cannot find a suitable solution for managing the model annotations when it comes to forms - e.g. display names and validation messages. The text book approach of using RESX files doesn't work for me for various reasons, one reason being that it seems that the RESX file has to reside in the main application and that is no good when using an unknown set of RCLs in the project - i.e. the RESX would have to carry all the translations for all the modules regardless of which I was using. I've tried the approach of overriding the DefaultModelMetadataProvider, but that sets the attribute meta data on start-up so it isn't scoped and therefore it is no good for me when the relevant CMS page is then loaded and the language/culture is then set. I've tried overriding the various model Attribute classes, but I can't obtain any scoped variables in there, so I can't use my translator/language service class to access the translation data. Can anybody think of another route I could try?

Comment: woah. Could you please reformat this question in a way that it's readable?

Comment: I think this article should help you: https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/localizing-data-annotation-attributes-in-asp-net-core